# How to get the correct diameter of a sphere given the volume

Tags: python, math, exponent

A few websites give the following equation for getting diameter from the volume of a sphere:

diameter = (6(V/pi))^1/3 i.e the cube root of 6(V/pi)

https://www.sensorsone.com/sphere-volume-to-diameter-calculator/

When using the following code my answer is out by a power of ten and I cannot see why

**Code**

```
from math import pi


vol = 36.0e-12 #pL

d =   (6*(vol/pi))**(1/3)
print("d : ", d)

d_millimetres = d * 1e3
print("d_millimetres : ", d_millimetres)


d_microns = d * 1e6
print("d_microns : ", d_microns)
```

**Returns**

```
d :  0.0004096704379531776
d_millimetres :  0.4096704379531776
d_microns :  409.67043795317755
```

**Desired answer**

40.9#microns

Comment: What unit is your volume? The `#pL` comment seems to indicate that you're thinking about picoliter (the correct abbreviation would be `pl` with lowercase l for liter). If you expect your result im meters then you should give the input in cubic meters. Liter is somewhat odd in the SI system as it is (10cm)³.

Comment: pico litres is what I was aiming at, pL is how I have always seen it referred to but that doesn't mean pL is correct.

Comment: I stand corrected, it looks like lowercase l and uppercase L are both appropriate for liter (or litre). Weird. Uppercase L was apparently adopted as a unit symbol a bit after I learned that stuff in school, so I feel somewhat excused. Btw, as was mentioned in another comment below, 36 pl/pL/picoliter/picolitre is 36.0e-15 m³.

Comment: Hi Hans, pico litres is 10^12 not 15. I tried the ^15 power and I do get the right answer then, but it is a picoliter and micron I enter in the online calculators and they always return 40.9microns. If it turns out to be something done I shall smack myself.

Comment: You still don't get it. pico litre is 10^-12 litre but 10^-15 cubic meter. You can only use litre based input if you expect your diameter output to be in dm (hundredth of meter) because a litre is one dm³. If you want to have outputs in meters you need to give input in cubic meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for a sphere is:

```
V = (4/3)πr3
```

Solving for `r`:

```
r = (3V/4/π)1/3
```

`d = 2r`, so:

```
d = 2((3V/4/π)1/3)
```

`23 = 8`, so moving 8 inside the cube root gives:

```
d = ((8*3V/4/π)1/3)
```

```
d = (6V/π)1/3
```

In Python:

```py
import math

def d(V):
    return (6*V/math.pi)**(1/3)

# NOTE! make units agree!  36 pL (36e-12 L) == 36e-15 cubic meters
print(d(36e-15))
```

Output:

```
4.0967043795317764e-05   # or 40.967 microns
```

Test with `r = 2, V = (4/3)π23 = 32/3π`:

```py
print(d(32/3*math.pi))
```

```
3.9999999999999996   # 4 expected
```

Comment: Hi, that's the answer I have above. According to all the online calculators I have found it is incorrect by a power of ten(I don't know why though).

Comment: @Windy71 It's correct.  Test it with a known value, like r=2 gives V=33.51, and d(33.51) gives 4.  What online calculator are you using and what are you entering?

Comment: Hi Mark, I posted one of the calculators in the question above and entered 36pL and the output diameter is 40.9micrometres.

Comment: @Windy71 a Liter is a cubic decimeter, or .1 meter.  That's your factor of 10.

Comment: @Windy71  pL ~= cubic microns, but cubic millimeters.  Off by a factor of 1000, or 10x after taking the cube root.  Updated my answer.

Comment: can you explain "# NOTE! make units agree!  36 pL == 36 cubic femtometers (36e-15 meters)" in layman's for me?

Comment: @Windy71 I misspoke.  I edited to meters, since the final answer is in meters.  You need cubic meters to get meters after taking the cube root.

Comment: so 1L = 0.001cubic metres, therefore when I state volume I must put it into cubic metres (not just pL) and divide it by 1000 to make fL?

Comment: Thankyou Mark and Hans, I get it now.

Comment: You entered liters, which must be divided by 1000 to convert to cubic meters.